# Passing data from Django view to D3

Tags: python, html, django, d3.js

Complete newbie question:

I have a Django app running in which I generate a view with data:

```
result = json.dumps(data)

context = RequestContext(request, {
    'result': result,
})

return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Now I have a `map.js` file in which I render a heat map of the data using `d3.js`.
I also have an `index.html` file where my page is rendered and the heatmap reference is passed via

```
<body>
 <div id="heatMap">
 </div>
<body>
```

Question: how do I pass my data generated in the view to the `map.js` file?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: what is the function that takes the input?

Comment: I have a d3 svg function to which I pass the data object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your template use `{{ result }}` in between `<script></script>` tags to do your JavaScript magic.

If `result` is a serialized JSON object you can just use `JSON.parse(result)` to convert the JSON string to a JavaScript object.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = JSON.parse("{{ result }}");
run_d3_stuff(data);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! so in my template I should have something like `<script src="map.js"> var data = {{ result }} </script>`?

Comment: almost. include your `heatmap.js` elsewhere and then just do a `<script type="text/javascript">var data = "{{ result }}"</script>` if `result` is a string. If result is a object you need to iterate through it to generate something meaningful in javascript

Comment: yes, result is a json object. I am trying to pass it to `d3` function as `.data()`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Basically I have a python dictionary converted to JSON that I am trying to pass to D3.

Comment: edited my answer. feel free to ask if there is still anything unclear

Answer (score 2):

There are a few potential solutions here.

The first, as noted by Alp, is to do this:

```
<script>
    run_d3_stuff('{{results}}'); //Use whatever your function is here.
</script>
```

Another solution is to render your script file using a view and include it in the target page.

EDIT:

To be more clear, the second solution would involve changing the template to be your JavaScript file, using the same trick above to set a variable's value to this. Then in your page you would do this:

```
<script src="my_view's_path"></script>
```

Comment: `var results = {{results}}` would only work if `result` is a number. put quotes around it if it's a string. do some looping if it's an array or object.

Comment: @Alp You're right, depending on the return type of the data you may need to massage it.

Comment: how do I declare/call that variable in .js file?